# Missing R interpreter in PyCharm

Tags: python, r, pycharm, ide

I'm using Python in PyCharm without any problems. Now I would like to learn R for personal development; but I couldn't manage to set it up into PyCharm. When I click "New Project" I can see R Package and R Project; but when I choose R Project I see a message "Missing R interpreter". When I try to choose file path: /usr/bin/R, it is empty.

I'm using Kubuntu, I have installed R via terminal. When I write:

```
which R
```

The output is:

```
/usr/bin/R
```

When I check the path for R folder (/usr/bin), I can't see an R folder there. More awkward is that if I type "R" in the terminal, R starts working. I also double checked with another IDE named RKWard where R works perfectly. But I don't want to use more than 1 IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing it with [PyCharms quickstart?](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/r-plugin-support.html#ui)
In order to use R in PyCharm you have to install [this plugin first.](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6632-r-language-for-intellij)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, it was because I installed Pycharm professional through Flathub. I removed the Flathub version and installed it from the tarball provided by JetBrains on their website, and was able to select my R interpreter.